# Module of exponential function

Tags: functional-analysis

In the Fourier transform $\hat{f}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\exp(-2\pi j w x)$. What is a value of $|\exp(-2\pi j w x)|$?

Answer (score 1):

If $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $j$ is the imaginary unit (what I ussually call $i$), then $|e^{-2\,\pi\,j\,w\cdot x}|=1$.

Comment: but, What are the intermediary steps please

Comment: by indentity of Euler I know that expresion is equal to $|\cos(-2\pi j w x)+\sin(-2\pi j w x)|$

Comment: @Juan Almost, by Euler you know that this is equal to $|\cos(-2\pi wx) + j\sin(-2\pi wx)| = (\cos^2 + \sin^2)^{1/2}\ldots$.

Comment: ok, understand thanks